# Explicit solution of parametric solutions of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, closed-form

I need to find the explicit solution of the following ODE:

$y'+\sin y'=x$, $y=y(x)$.

I have found these two parametric solutions:

$x=t+\sin t$ and $y=\frac{t^2}{2}+t\sin t+\cos t+c$, $c\in\Bbb R$.

Any idea if it exists?

Edit: My teacher mentions in the rubric of the exercise to find the solutions in closed form. My question is if closed-form solutions include parametric solutions.

Comment: How you get parametric solutions ?

Comment: Let t=y' then x=t+sint and dy/dx=t. By using the chain rule and calculating some integrals, you can easily be lead to the above results.

Comment: A parametric solution is a closed form imo. I think here that is the best you can do. It looks like finding $y(x)$ requires you to invert $x(t)$ to get $t(x)$, but as far as I know $x = t + \sin(t)$ has no solution in elementary functions.

Comment: @Winther I am basically looking if the parametric solutions can be transformed into an explicit solution of the above ODE.

Comment: What do you mean by explicit? Maybe I misunderstood you. I read your post as: 'I want to find a formula $y(x)$ from the parametric solution'.

Comment: No, I mean the same thing with you (that's what explicit solution means), the problem is if there exists a function $f$ for which: $y=f(x)$, so that it is a solution of the ODE.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729, see my post below.

Answer (score 1):

let $f$  be defined by $$f(y) = y + \sin y.$$  it is not hard to see that  $f$ is invertible.   we have $$ f(y') = x \to y' = f^{-1}(x)$$ integrating the last equation gives $$y = \int f^{-1}(x) \, dx \tag 1$$ we can make a change of variabe $u = f^{-1}(x), x = f(u), dx = f'(u) \, du = (1 + \cos u)du.$ with this change of variable $(1)$ becomes $$ y = \int u (1 + \cos u) \, du = \frac12 u^2+u\sin u + \cos u + c, u = f^{-1}(x).$$

Comment: @Winther, i did not understand op/s solution. i can delete it if it is not helpful.

Comment: As I understand it, from his comments below the question, OP is asking if there exist a closed form $y(x)$ of this parametric solution.